# Feedparser Missing Elements in MRSS Feed

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I'm trying to parse an MRSS feed that has video entries and some metadata for those videos. Here is one entry:

```
<item>
  <title>Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone</title>
  <guid>http://video.videos.com/watch/harry-potter</guid>
  <link>http://video.videos.com/watch/harry-potte</link>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Mar 2017 21:29:47 +0000</pubDate>
  <media:title>Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone</media:title>
  <media:description>"Harry Potter battles Voldemort"</media:description>
  <media:status state="active"/>
  <media:category label="Magic">Magic</media:category>
  <brand:id>123456</brand:id>
  <brand:credit type="main">Emma Watson</brand:credit>
  <brand:credit type="main">Daniel Radcliffe</brand:credit>
  <brand:credit type="videographer">Universal</brand:credit>
  <brand:category>Magic</brand:category>
  <brand:premiere_date>Mon, 6 Mar 2017 11:00:00 +0000</brand:premiere_date>
  <brand:lastModifiedDate>Fri, 03 Mar 2017 21:29:47 +0000</brand:lastModifiedDate>
</item>
```

When I parse this with `feedparser` I get all the keys, but `entry.brand_credit` results in `{'type': u'videographer'}`. 
What I was hoping to get was a list of some sort, perhaps like:

```
[{'main':'Emma Watson'},{'main':'Daniel Radcliffe'},{'videographer':'Universal'}]`
```

Or really just all of the names in a non-dictionaried list. Is there a reason that `feedparser` is skipping to the last `<brand:credit>` tag? Is there a way to find the others?